# jQuery Validate determine which button used in a form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to determine button was used to submit the form.

I have two buttons - cancel and submit within the form and depending on which one is clicked I want to carry out some functions before the submit happens.

I can determine the value from the POST in the server side but need to do so on the client side first

What jquery function do I call to determine if the 'cancel' button was used?

The submit of the form is being handled as part of the submitHandler event of jquery validation.

Here's the elements:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

Here's the submit handler:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct by not wanting to use external or additional `click` handlers with the jQuery Validate plugin since the plugin already automatically captures the `submit` `click` event with its `submitHandler` callback.

Your problem is that you do not really have a "cancel" button.  This is nothing more than a duplicate `submit` button...

```
<input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

No matter what you do, the plugin is always going to treat its `click` event as a regular form submit.  What if you change it into a `<button></button>`?  Still no good.  The plugin also treats the `button`'s `click` event as a regular form submit.  There is no other callback function/option built-in to this plugin that can capture any other kind of button/cancel `click` event.

Your only option is to place it *outside* of your `<form></form>` tags.  The Valdiate plugin will not see it and you can then bind your own `click` event to it.

Your own `cancel` click event:

```
$('[name="cancel"]').click(function() {
    // your code that handles a cancel click
});
```

**Demo using `<input type="submit"`: http://jsfiddle.net/wZwcQ/**

**Demo using `<button></button>`:  http://jsfiddle.net/h7XKc/**

Comment: Hi. I understand this. Thank you. I'm surprised jquery doesnt have the ability to interrogate a form ie the values of the form that will be included in the submit method - in this case POST. Is there a javascript object that could be interrogated?

Comment: @Ray, I'm not sure how you mean... both of your `input`s are `type='submit'`.  So if you include them both inside of `<form></form>`, there's no way for the plugin to differentiate; it's just listening for the `submit` event which will occur from either one.

Comment: On a server side script in php I could interrogate the $_POST variable and if $_POST['cancel'] was set I would know that was the button used to submit the form and execute the script accordingly. On research I understand only those items with values are sent with an HTML POST. I assumed I could do a similar check on the client side with either Jquery or Javascript. ie test which ever value was to be included in the POST. if 'cancel' I'd know it was the cancel, if submit i'd know it was the submit etc. hope that makes sense

Comment: @Ray, You could probably do that with jQuery as suggested in other answers.  But that has nothing to do with the built-in `submitHandler` of the Validate plugin.  It's far simpler to just pull your cancel button out of the `form`... "cancel" is not posting any data so there's really nothing semantic about it being inside the `<form></form>` tags anyway.

Comment: Hi. Agreed. I re-thought my logic on the script and have gone with this solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
   $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('form submitted');
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(':submit').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).attr('name') == 'submit') {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });

    $('[name="cancel"]').click(function () {
        // your code that handles a cancel click
        alert('form cancelled');
        return false;
    });
```

Live [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vrag6/1/)

Greetings.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. This method though creates a separate on click function which I understand. How though can I interact this with the validation plugins submitHandler? Is there anyway I can interrogate the form object and determine whether cancel or submit value has been set?

Comment: [This is not going to work](http://jsfiddle.net/vrag6/).  The plugin's built in `submitHandler` is still going to capture the submit event and submit the form after you click the "cancel" button.  http://jsfiddle.net/vrag6/

Comment: @Sparky if you add `return false` in the click event of the button _cancel_, the form not is submited... Greetings.

Comment: Again, the plugin does not need a whole new `click` event handler for `submit` when it already has one built in.